# google data studio conditional statement on calculated field

Tags: looker-studio

I am using google data studio and I am trying to create a calculated field using a `case` statement, but it is not working. The metric is sales. Bellow is the sample line:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(sales) > 350000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

The formula above gives me an error. If I do the formula bellow instead it doesn't give an error but the result is not what I expect:

```
CASE WHEN sales > 350000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Any idea what could be wrong ? I tried to use `if` as well without success.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two calculated fields. Using the first calculated field in the next one with the `CASE` statement:

**Calc Field 1: Summed Sales**

```
SUM(sales)
```

**Calc Field 2: MyCaseField**

```
CASE WHEN Summed Sales > 350000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**From the Data Studio Docs:**

> ...It's not possible to do math or use calculated field functions in a
>   WHEN condition...   ...You can work around this by first creating a
>   calculated field with the desired formula. Then use that field in the
>   CASE statement.

[Reference](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724?hl=en)