# IF statement equivalent in Google Data Studio

Tags: if-statement, looker-studio

I am trying to replicate the Excel formula
`IF(AND('cost'> 0, 'orders' = 0),"TRUE")` in Google Data Studio using the `CASE` statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN COST > 0 AND ORDERS = 0 THEN "TRUE"
END
```

However, I receive the following error:

> *Only numeric literals are allowed if aggregated fields are used in CASE*

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google data studio conditional statement on calculated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824522/google-data-studio-conditional-statement-on-calculated-field)

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

Use **Either** #1 or #2.
To elaborate on the difference between using `"True"` and `TRUE`, the **Semantic Type** of:

- #1 is **Boolean** (`TRUE` or `FALSE`);
- #2 is a **Text** field (note the quotes around `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"`):

### 1) [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770)

The **Conditional Function**, [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770), was introduced in the [11 Mar 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#mar-11-2021); thus, tweaking the [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770) function in the question now works as expected in Google Data Studio.
**Note**: The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below is a **Boolean** field; thus, to create a **Text** field, replace `TRUE` with `"TRUE"` and replace `FALSE` with `"FALSE"`:

```
IF(Cost > 0 AND Orders = 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

### 2) [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724)

Alternatively, the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement proposed in the question should work as expected. That said, the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement below explicitly states the `ELSE` clause.
**Note**: The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below is a **Text** field; thus, to create a **Boolean** field, replace `"TRUE"` with `TRUE` and replace `"FALSE"` with `FALSE`:

```
CASE
  WHEN Cost > 0 AND Orders = 0 THEN "TRUE"
  ELSE "FALSE"
END
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/8668f2bf-0d94-4bf3-b3ce-43eef425561b) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is an `IF` statement in Google Data Studio; however, your `CASE` `WHEN` should work. I tried to reproduce your problem:

1. I created a Google Sheet with two columns, `cost` and `orders`, and filled in some numbers
2. I created a data source connected to this sheet
3. I made a table in a Google Data Studio report using this data source, and added a calculated field with your exact formula
4. It didn't give me any error messages and the field values are as expected

From the error message it feels like this is related to where your data source comes from.

Answer (score -1):

The Google Data Studio team released a new `IF` function and a more convenient way to use `CASE`.

The update: *[Release notes (11 Mar 2021)](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#mar-11-2021)*

```
IF(Actual Sales > Forecast Sales, Bonus * 1.2, Bonus)
```

The documentation is in [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770?hl=en).

If it's not working, then use the below `CASE` documentation link. It is supposed to appear on the sidebar just where the two `CASE` support articles are.

```
CASE Premium Status
    WHEN "Platinum" THEN CONCAT(Site URL, "platinum_welcome.html")
    WHEN "Gold" THEN CONCAT(Site URL, "gold_welcome.html")
    WHEN "Silver" THEN CONCAT(Site URL, "silver_welcome.html")
    ELSE CONCAT(Site URL, "welcome.html")
END
```

*[CASE (simple)](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10471275)*